# Weak functions with single-file header libraries

Tags: c, gcc, header-files, libraries

I maintain rawdraw, and rawdraw uses global symbols to callback, for creation, input, and closure.  I would like automatically use one copy of a symbol, say, a no-op if the user has not defined one, or if the user has defined one, I would want to use it.

This isn't a problem for most platforms, but for Android it's incredibly annoying because you can't identify linker issues until the app is running on-device.

The issue is this is in the header.  So what I want is a way to, from the same C file, allow a function call to be overridden, but not require it.

I've tried both `weak` and `weak,aliasof(...)` attributes and neither seem to allow overriding of a symbol in the same C file.

For example, in this case, a user wants to allow detection of window termination, but many users of this library don't care.

cnfg.h

```c
void HandleWindowTermination();

...

    case APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW:
              ...
        HandleWindowTermination();
        break;
```

Would require the user to implement `HandleWindowTermination()` - but I would like to have an optional implementation of it.

```c
void DefaultHandleWindowTermination() { } // Do nothing
```

That is only used if `HandleWindowTermination()` is never defined.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are doing?

Comment: I've added an example, in this case it's specifically what the new PR has asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC "weak" attribute is not available for all targets. From the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html):

> This attribute requires assembler and object file support, and may not be available on all targets.

Hence you may need to use a work-around. One possibility could be to define a function pointer to an optional implementation:

```
   typedef void (* HandleWindowTerminationFuncType) ();
   HandleWindowTerminationFuncType HandleWindowTerminationFunction = NULL;

   static void HandleWindowTermination()
   {
       if(HandleWindowTerminationFunction != NULL)
       {
           HandleWindowTerminationFunction();
       }
       else
       {
           // Default action
       }
   }
```

Another module may then implement a `HandleWindowTermination()` function and set the  `HandleWindowTerminationFunction` pointer to point at that implementation (you may implement a "setter" function to do that).